# Syntax highlighting text editor for MAC that supports c# & asp

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos, text-editor

I primarily program on a macbook air. Occasionally I need to do some quick editing of sites built on .net. However these are usually not too complicated and I would like to avoid using virtualization to us a windows based program due to the resources of my machine.

So what I am looking for is something that will allow me to make and edit simple C# and .asp pages. I don't need code completion (although I wouldn't complain) or anything fancy.. just basic syntax highlighting.

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are off topic here. Take a look at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to answer Notepad++, but a quick look up shows it's not ported to Mac OS. So googling for Notepad++ on Mac revealed [this article](http://studiogreenleaf.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/notepad-on-mac-osx/), citing:

> When I use Mac OSX, though, I was using TextEdit, the bundled
>   application that ships with OSX similar to Window’s Wordpad.  It
>   finally dawned on me that I can use WINE to run the Notepad++ .exe
>   file in MacOSX–sure enough, the Notepad++ v6.1.2 Installer worked like
>   a charm and I now have a fully-functional Notepad++ on OSX.

Disclaimer - only Googled this for you; can't guarantee it'll work. But if it does, you'll get a nice editor, IMO.

Comment: Well, It's certainly worth a shot. Thanks, I'll post my results once I've gotten a chance to attempt this solution.

Comment: So, after looking into it, the WINE solution looks like it would be a very good solution but requires a little up front work to get everything installed and running. I used the idea though and used an app called crossover that took care of everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is pretty cool, it has syntax highlighting for c# and many other languages

Answer (score 0):

One editor that I was able to find that filled my requrements was notepad++. I was able to run it on my mac using crossover. This is not free, but there are free light weight solutions that allow windows editors to be used on a mac.

hope this is helpful!